# Why my code of lifetime function call is ok or fail?

Tags: rust, lifetime

1. I'm new to Rust lang and wonder what difference between two blocks in `fn main()`, can anyone explain in words of lifetime.
2. Are .`as_str()` calls change the lifetime of x and y?
3. Whose lifetime does `-> &a' str` refer to? a,b,c at `lifetime()` returning position or z to receive the result?

I consider the variables x and y have the same lifetime scopes in both blocks. And that of z covers the x's and y's.

If `(x: &'a str, y: &'a str, z: &'a str)` demands same lifetime scope of x,y,z, both blocks should fail.

```
fn main()
{
    let mut z = "123abc";

    {////    CAN ONLY SUCCEED WHEN REMOVE THE BRACES OF THIS BLOCK
        let x = String::from("ajoisd");
        let y = String::from("aso");
        z = lifetime(x.as_str(), y.as_str(), z);
    }

    {////    GOES WELL WITH/WITHOUT BRACES
        let x = "ajoisd";
        let y = "aso";
        z = lifetime(x, y, z);
    }

    println!("{}", z);
}

fn lifetime<'a>(a: &'a str, b: &'a str, c: &'a str) -> &'a str
{
    if a.len() > b.len()          {a}
    else if a.len() < b.len()     {b}
    else                          {c}
}
```

Comment: If you don't like the if...else, you can use a match instead of that weird formatting: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=617851d2504360720adcddabc6a3eb2f

Comment: The book explains those differences in chapter 10, section 3: [Validating References with Lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html)

Answer (score 2):

Strings `"ajoisd"` and `"aso"` have the `'static` lifetime. They outlive any variable in the program. Variables `x` and `y` in the first block live only in this block which is less than the lifetime of `z`.